# Django IntegrityError NOT Null Constraint Failed reqs_student.section_id

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, and I'm trying to create an application with a user signup form where students can sign up with their name, subjects, and section, but it has an error at the sections part.

I am getting an error of `NOT NULL constraint failed: reqs_student.section_id`.

These are the relevant bits of code:

forms.py:

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
subjects = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    required=False
)

section = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Section.objects.all(),
    widget=forms.Select,
    required=True
)

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User

@transaction.atomic
def save(sel codef, commit = True):
    user = super().save()
    user.is_student = True
    user.save()
    student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
    student.subjects.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('subjects'))
    student.section = self.cleaned_data.get('section')
    return user
```

Model code:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, 
    related_name='section')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='subjected_students')
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Student_Section')
```

View code:

```
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
model = User
form_class = StudentSignUpForm
template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    login(self.request, user)
    return redirect('students:requirement_list')
```

According to the traceback, the code starts having an error at
user = form.save()

Full Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/student/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['reqs.apps.ReqsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  298.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: reqs_student.section_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/reqs/views/students.py" in form_valid
  26.         user = form.save()

File "/Users/JLudan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
  52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/reqs/forms.py" in save
  45.         student = Student.objects.create(user=user)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/JLudan/Downloads/Trackle-master3/Trackle/trackle/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  298.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /signup/student/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: reqs_student.section_id
```

What can be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `section` before you save the student.

```
section = self.cleaned_data['section']  # No need to use get() here
student = Student.objects.create(user=user, section=section)
student.subjects.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('subjects'))
```